# Bent/Inverted Kaf in Torah Scroll, Parshas Bereishis

Tags: torah-service, mistakes, torah-reading, safrus, parashat-bereishit

If a Torah reader finds certain writing errors in a Torah scroll, the scroll may be invalid, and the congregation would be required to take out a different one to continue the service. Some errors, however, are considered minor, and the service could be continued using that scroll, with the error to be fixed at a later time.

In a discussion of possible errors in the "laws" section of my [Tikkun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikkun_%28book%29) (Jerusalem: Mishor, 1990), one was mentioned at Genesis 3:24: the verse ends, "לשמר את דרך עץ החיים" -- "to keep the way of the tree of life". The issue deals with the final Kaf ך of the word דרך (way). If the Kaf is הפוכה (inverted), then you could continue reading from that scroll. But if the Kaf is כפופה (bent over; that is, it was written כ, as its medial form), then a new one must be taken out.

What is the background for these rules? Why would someone want to invert or bend/medialize the Kaf on this particular verse, and if so, why is one worse than the other?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18402/759

Answer (score 3):

I can't really answer the question that asked for "the background for the[] rules" about what makes a *sefer* invalid. But as to why "[someone would] want to invert or bend the Kaf on this particular verse, and if so, why is one worse than the other", there are many oddly-shaped letters in various parts of the Torah in various traditions, many of which are listed in *Tora Sh'lema* in a special section after... er, um, *M'tzora* maybe? You'll often see these in the *m'sora*, and *Baal Haturim* quotes quite a few of them. (*Rashi* also quotes a few IIRC.)

Comment: msh, your answer leads to the following difference:  Since we find inverted letters in the Torah, we can say that if a letter was mistakenly inverted, it still retains its form.  But changing a peshuta into a kefufa is a different form.

Comment: @YDK, perhaps so: I don't know. Halachic question: Is it the rule in general (not on this _pasuk_) that exchanging final and medial forms invalidates the _sefer_?

Comment: In Maseches Sofrim 2:10, it says: "כל האותיות הכפולין בא׳׳ב כותב את הראשונים
בתחלת התיבה ובאמצע התיבה והאחרונים בסוף ואם שינה פסול" -- For all of the "double" letters in the alphabet [i.e. those that have final and medial forms]: one writes the medial forms in the beginning or middle of a word, and the final forms at the end of the word. If one deviates from this rule, [the scroll] is invalid.