# Is there knowledge of which Levi'im are descendants of Moshe?

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu, levites-leviyim

Clearly any Cohen is a (patriarchal) direct descendant of Aaron.

Probably some of the rest of the tribe of Levi are direct descendants of Moshe, but there were of course lots of other Levi'im in that generation as well.

Do we know whether Moshe has descendants to this day, and is there any hint as to who has a tradition of being one?

Comment: See: Midrash Tanchuma Pinchas 11, Or HaChaim on Exodus 32:32:9, 1 Chronicles 23:17, Berachos 7a

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26046