# why פ and ס spaces?

Tags: tanach

Why is the Tanak spaced at the end of certain verses with a פ or ס?

Comment: david macias jr, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for bringing your question here. Your question may be easier for others to answer if you [edit] it to indicate where you saw this. (Was it some particular print of the _Tanach_?) I hope you stick around and enjoy the site.

Answer (score 5):

There are four ways of writing a paragraph break in the Torah text:

1)

`xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
              xxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

2)

`xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx        xxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

3)

`xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

4)

`xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

According to the Rambam, 1 and 4 are called פתוחות "open" breaks, while 2 and 3 are called סתומות "closed" breaks. According to the Rosh 1 and 3 are called פתוחות "open" breaks, while 2 and 4 are called סתומות "closed" breaks.

In a printed text open breaks are often denoted with a פ and closed breaks are often denoted with a ס, using the initial letter of the Hebrew name.

The open breaks are considered a stronger gap than the closed breaks.

Type 3 and 4 are used only when the text ends too close to the end of the line to allow for types 1 and 2 to be used. In most modern Torah scrolls, scribes will have arranged the lines to only need use type 1 and 2 in order to avoid deciding between the Rambam and Rosh, although if forced to, it is generally accepted that the Rambam's position is the primary one (see ShA YD 275:2).

Comment: Thank you for that explanation, I still have a feeling that they seem like puzzle pieces that are meant to be grouped together thematically , one day when I am more capable I hope to try that theory שלום

Comment: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:ccPL1V1ROPQJ:www.herzog.ac.il/vtc/0077320.doc+&cd=6&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

Comment: http://www.maharitz.co.il/?CategoryID=308&ArticleID=1582

Comment: Is [this](http://www.hakirah.org/Vol17Epstein.pdf) of use?