# Parshat Miketz in one bloc

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, sefer-torah, miketz

I am looking for any significance about why parshat Miketz is written in one solid bloc, with no break at all, except the fact that the Parsha begins at the beginning of a line.

Unlike parshat Vayetzei (beginning of the Parsha on the same line with a 9 letter gap with the end of the previous Parsha), Vayechi (beginning of the Parsha with only one letter gap with the previous word of the previous Parsha) and the Balak story (beginning of the same line with a 9 letter gap and the end of Parsha deals with the Pinchas story at a new line) I am not finding anything about it in the classic mefarshim about Miketz being a single bloc

Gut Shabbos

Comment: Hi, I don't know what you mean by "unlike parshat vayetzei". Both vayetze and miketz are entirely one parsha-section.

Comment: @DoubleAA I think the "unlike" refers to the end of the sentence about nothing in the classic mefarshim

Comment: (fyi about ways to mark a section break https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/60709/759)

Comment: @DoubleAA, Miketz is unique in the sense of it is one single unit with no break in the entire Parsha BUT begins at a new line. Vayetzei does NOT begin at a new line - despite being a single bloc.

Comment: @Heshy, you also right. It is what I meant

Comment: @Eli83 Vayetzei DOES begin at a new line if you happened to finish the previous verse close to the end of the line. Most scribes nowadays try not to do that, but it certainly has happened sometimes. See my link above.

Comment: In any event, @Eli83 why does it matter here what section break type precedes Miketz? The interesting thing is it's a very long section, not what section break type precedes it. In that regard it's exactly the same as Vayeitzei.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I may be wrong but I believe it does matter because the mefarshim are silent on the matter, and they probably make a distinction between all the little structural differences of the text. How would you explain they are so silent on this obvious structure of Parshat Miketz? It is very bizare

Comment: Do the mefarshim comment about all the other cases you listed? Why should they comment here?

Comment: @DoubleAA, yes they do. On Vayetzei see Baal Haturim Bereshit 28:10. On Vayechi, see the famous Rashi Ber.47:28. On parshat Balak see the Gemara Berachot 12b

Comment: That's not exactly what they are saying. Rashi is just saying Vaychi starts without any parsha gap there, nothing about the whole sidra Vaychi. The Gemara isn't commenting on the sidra Balak at all, but just how we can't split things up. The Baal Haturim is likely just noting the opening is a stuma as opposed to a ptucha, but even if he means the whole sidra then he doesn't mean the opening structure. Either way you have no precedent of someone specifically caring about both like you do.