# If the "Nun" preceding Bamidbar (Num) 10:35 is not upside down, is the Torah still kosher?

Tags: halacha, aleph-bet-letters, sefer-torah, safrus, behaalotcha-parsha

While reading last week's parsha, I noticed that the letter "*nun*" immediately preceding the verse *Vayehi B'nso'ah ha'aron* [Bamidbar 10:35](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0410.htm#35) was written as regular *nun* (tagin on top) rather than upside down, as the majority of Sifrei Torah seem to have this. I base myself in this on my own experience as a Ba'al Kri'ah over 30 years and having seen about 200 different sifrei Torah in that time that ALL have them. (See Talmud [Shabbat 115b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=115b&format=pdf) - 116a, for the source of the symbols, though it's not apparent that the format is specifically a *nun*, there.) The *nun* after verse 36 was upside down.

Does this make the Torah passul? I am surmising that it might, because one might argue that this is like an extra letter written in the Torah, which should not be there. Incidentally, there was a space between the 1st *nun* and the preceding as well as the next parsha, so it did not look like it was attached to any word.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38131

Comment: There are a number of traditions as to how (and if) to write these markers. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_nun  for instance and note the examples (particularly from L.C.) here http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Inverted_nun also http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51444&st=&pgnum=135

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**If the *Nun*'s were not inverted but were left as regular letters, it is kosher *bdieved*.**

Source: [*Sefer Keses Hasofer (Mahadura Tinyana)*, *Chakira 17*](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41270&st=&pgnum=140) (s.v. *v'hinei hageonum*) citing *Noda Beyhudah* and others
(*Sefer Keses Hasofer* is the classic source for *Hilchos Stam* by Rav Shlomo Ganzfried, the author of the *Kitzur Shulchan Aruch* and is probably the standard text for learning hilchos *Safrus*.)

If the *Nun*'s were completely left out the Torah is also kosher *b'dieved* .

Source: [*Sefer Keses Hasofer* (15:8)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41270&st=&pgnum=67) in the name of the *Bnei Yonah* and *Teshuvos Maharam Lublin* disagreeing with *Maharshal*.

[Here is the sefer Keses Hasofer (Mahadura Tinyana)](http://hebrewbooks.org/41270)