# Which way should the Tagin be on a nun hafuchah (upside down nun)?

Tags: safrus, behaalotcha-parsha, tagin

In a written Torah, there are two upside down *nun*'s - one before [Bemidbar 10:35](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14084&st=&pgnum=122&hilite=) and another after Bemidbar 10:36.

When the Sofer writes this, should the tagin ("crowns") be placed on top (i.e., inline with the tops of the surrounding letters, which in this case would be on the bottom part of the nun), or should he place them on the bottom (meaning the "head of the upside down nun, as if the nun were written the normal way?)

The one I used this Shabbat has the tagin on the top - inline / parallel to the surrounding letters. I think this incorrect. If the nun includes the tagin, then if the nun is upside down, the tagin should be upside-down as well. I.e. flipping the nun, includes a flip of the tagin.

Comment: Somewhat related:[This M.Y. question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/40129/5275)

Comment: I don't know why you say these are "upside down _nun_'s". What makes you think they should be upside down? (Frankly I'm not even sure why you'd think these need Taggim at all.)

Comment: @DoubleAA That's an interesting point based on what Kesset Hasofer suggests. However, if these are considered punctuation marks (as he suggests), they are shaped like an upside down nun, and in all the sifrei Torah I have seen, they have taggin as every nun does. I'm not sure how to edit my question with including this info.

Comment: "if these are considered punctuation marks (as he suggests), they are shaped like an upside down nun" Again, why do you think they are shaped like upside down nuns? They might be flipped horizontally, or otherwise changed without being upside down.

Comment: @DoubleAA Sounds like it depends on the meaning of "hafuch"? Am I getting that right?

Comment: Doesn't the Mahrshal have a teshuva on this?