# Why a (enda)mem sofit לםרבה in Yishaya 9:6

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, aleph-bet-letters, isaiah-yeshaya-the-book

I noticed during the reading of the haftorah of parshas Yisro that the word למרבה is spelled לםרבה,this is certainly a strange phenomenon since a mem sofit everywhere else is always at the end of the word.  Why is it written this way and what is it teaching us?

Passuk 9:6 :

לםרבה [לְמַרְבֵּ֨ה] הַמִּשְׂרָ֜ה וּלְשָׁל֣וֹם אֵֽין־קֵ֗ץ עַל־כִּסֵּ֤א דָוִד֙ וְעַל־מַמְלַכְתּ֔וֹ לְהָכִ֤ין אֹתָהּ֙ וּֽלְסַעֲדָ֔הּ בְּמִשְׁפָּ֖ט וּבִצְדָקָ֑ה מֵעַתָּה֙ וְעַד־עוֹלָ֔ם קִנְאַ֛ת יְהוָ֥ה צְבָא֖וֹת תַּעֲשֶׂה־זֹּֽאת

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/18405/759

Answer (score 4):

[Rada"k and Ibn Ezra](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/80201/why-a-endamem-sofit-%D7%9C%D7%9D%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%94-in-yishaya-96) offer slightly different interpretations, here. I don't quite understand Ibn Ezra's so I will summarize Radak's:

He says that this is an allusion to the time that they shall close (the mem sofit is a "closed" mem) the walls of Jerusalem that had been breached (opened) during all the years of exile. At that time, i.e., the time of the Messiah, the kingdom (rulership) that had been closed all these years, will be opened.

Answer (score 4):

The gemara in [Sanhedrin 94a](http://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.94a?lang=he) says this is an allusion to Hashem's desire to make Chizkiyahu moshiach which was 'closed off' and did not happen.

> א"ר תנחום דרש בר קפרא בציפורי מפני מה כל מ"ם שבאמצע תיבה פתוח וזה סתום ביקש הקב"ה לעשות חזקיהו משיח וסנחריב גוג ומגוג אמרה מדת הדין לפני הקב"ה רבש"ע ומה דוד מלך ישראל שאמר כמה שירות ותשבחות לפניך לא עשיתו משיח חזקיה שעשית לו כל הנסים הללו ולא אמר שירה לפניך תעשהו משיח לכך נסתתם

The story continues there if anyone is interested.

Comment: did we post answer at same time

Comment: @sam Looks like it. Great minds?:)

Answer (score 3):

Masheches Sanhedrin 94a asks this question and answers that really Chizkiyahu was supposed to be Mashiach and Sancheirav would have fulfilled the role of Gog Umagog. However ,Midas hadin said before HaShem that Dovid who sang shirah on everything you didnt make him Mashiach and Chizkiyahu who you did many miracles didnt say shirah your going to make him Mashiach?! For that reason the mem is closed to show that this idea was closed off because of midas hadin which would not allow it,it was an expression of end of ghe discussion.

למרבה המשרה ולשלום אין קץ וגו' א"ר תנחום דרש בר קפרא בציפורי מפני מה כל מ"ם שבאמצע תיבה פתוח וזה סתום ביקש הקב"ה לעשות חזקיהו משיח וסנחריב גוג ומגוג אמרה מדת הדין לפני הקב"ה רבש"ע ומה דוד מלך ישראל שאמר כמה שירות ותשבחות לפניך לא עשיתו משיח חזקיה שעשית לו כל הנסים הללו ולא אמר שירה לפניך תעשהו משיח לכך נסתתם