# Strange letters according to Sefer haTaggin

Tags: tanach, mesorah-tradition, safrus

[My chevrusoh](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/679/yitzchak) mentioned last week that there is a sefer entitled *Sefer haTaggin* which discusses all of the [strange letters](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18402/is-the-winding-%D7%A4-in-this-sefer-torah-kosher/18475#18475) found in Tana"ch.

Is there a collection of these letters and their forms (including the rolled פ, linked above) and where they are found in Tana"ch ? Ideally, such an answer would consist of a community wiki listed the sefer, perek, passuk, word(, and when applicable, which instance of the letter within the word) eg. `Gen 1:1 the large ב in בראשית.`

Comment: אותיות לפופות? ..

Comment: https://www.google.co.il/search?q=%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA+%D7%9C%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%AA&tbm=isch&source=hp&safe=active&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjclr_uqJDgAhU0SxUIHbNyC3AQsAR6BAgFEAE&biw=1920&bih=927

Comment: There are dozens of different lists. This is not feasible for us in one answer

Comment: See תורה שלמה: he has a list after or before תזריע or מצורע.

Comment: Sefer Taggin was republished nicely by R' Yaakov Basser out of Toronto a few years ago. You'd enjoy methinks

Comment: @DoubleAA, this is the first I learn of it. Where would I find his edition ?